# Substituir extract?

Tags: php, segurança

Analisando uma aplicação com a ferramenta RIPS, descobri que a parte do menu principal utiliza essas funções abaixo e é extremamente vulnerável:

```
extract( $_POST );
extract( $_GET );
extract( $_SESSION );
```

Qual é melhor maneira para substituir essas funções acima sem que não interfira na aplicação ?

Comment: Teria que fazer as atribuições manualmente ou dependendo do código isolar ele em uma função com o `extract()` pelo menos isso reduz o escopo das variáveis.

Comment: tem algum exemplo que pode me ajudar ?

Comment: o exemplo mais simples seria `$nome = $_POST['nome']`, é muito código?

Comment: sim, tem em vários arquivos .